# Subclipse does not recognize my project as an SVN project

Tags: subclipse

From SVN I checked out a "myproject" folder to my hard drive.
It happens to be an Eclipse project, so I imported it into Eclipse and I can work on it.

I have Subclipse installed and working as expected on other projects in the same Eclipse workspace.
But for some reason, "myproject" does not have the usual Subclipse controls like Team>Commit or the decorations.

Did I miss any obvious steps?

svn --version: 1.6.5 (r38866)
Subclipse: 1.6.6
Eclipse: jee-galileo-SR1-linux-gtk 20090920-1017

Here is what happens when I click Team>Share>SVN:

[Subclipse Team Share http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/7308/screenshotsubclipse.png](http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/7308/screenshotsubclipse.png)

Please note the root .svn folder.
On the command-line, SVN works in this folder.

Comment: Which tool and version did you use to check out the project to your drive? Also, what version of Subclipse are you running?

Comment: I use the "svn" command-line tool to check out. I edited my question to add all of the version numbers.

Comment: Could you add the steps you went through to do your import? I have run through a few scenarios and Subclipse seems to find the metadata every time. The only time it did not is if there was an extra folder between where the project was located and where the main directory of the working copy (with a .svn subfolder).

I'm primarily using Windows, so I'm not sure if I am going to be able to reproduce the issue or provide more insight, but someone else may be able to.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try right-clicking "myproject" and click Team / Share Project. It should ask you what type of repository, and when you move to the next screen it should indicate that it sees existing SVN/ directories at which point it should use that metadata to establish the link. It may also require that you have the SVN repository set up (in the SVN Repositories perspective).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added a screenshot to show what appears when I click on Team>Share. The SVN repository IS set up in the SVN repositories perspective.

Comment: Add following the steps you mentioned it tries to make a commit to the repository as well. I don;t want to trigger a commit. Any work around for this.

Comment: @Bagira, I typically am not working in Eclipse these days, so I don't have an environment to check it out. What does SVN show is modified?

Answer (score 12):

You can also remove the project (don't delete contents) and import it as existing project again.

Comment: Ah, these kludges. Wouldn't it better to find a real solution to a problem instead of something like "Restart the computer, dummy!"

Comment: it´s a 30 seconds solution that worked for me (while most voted solution didn't).

Answer (score 2):

OK I got to here after handling the same error 
Now I've found my error(and solution) , maybe it is something that may help others here

My problem was that my repository was in **different** version than my tortoise-svn !!

As found out :
my repo. was of version 1.6 while I was using version 1.8 !

just downgraded it to 1.6 and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have **just installed Subclipse plugin**, already restarted the Eclipse but no SVN recognized:

- close the project and open it again
- F5 to refresh
- It should recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this in case someone runs into a similar situation.  I'm running eclipse luna with the subclipse plugin.

I've done this before without mishap, but svn is one of the more "touchy" source control repositories I've worked with.

I wanted to move a png logo file into my app.  So I renamed the existing one to a logo_bak and then imported the new one and then named it the same name as the existing logo that I just renamed logo_bak.  I then checked in some files and went on my way to other tasks.

However, the next work day when I started up eclipse luna my entire project was "dirty" as indicated by the svn label decoration for dirty on the project.

> (A file that is marked as "dirty" needs to be committed, an
>   "unversioned" file hasn't been added to your SVN repository yet, and
>   so on.)

and I just couldn't get it to synchronize with svn.  I also found that my files never did get checked in.  If I did a right click on my project, then Team - Share Project, that option wasn't displaying and Team - Synchronize with Repository was disabled.

I tried creating a new project, deleting metadata from eclipse, opening then closing the project, and several other things, but what worked was disconnecting the project from svn, then connecting back to it again.  After that I was able to right click on the project, then select Team - Share Project.  Then when I synchronized I had about a dozen or so files to Override and update, even though when I checked on differences they were the same as what was in the repo.  After that though everything started working again normally.